# Creating an entity reference in a custom entity

Tags: database, entities

I have created an entity that I want to collect data with from an external source and I want to reference that data to a node. How should i set up that entity in DB so it can properly reference a node? Can I use entity_id that references nid? And I want my entity to be non-fieldable so it does not take up unnecessary space and time.

Thanks.

Comment: The entity reference module provides a field, so you won't be able to use it with a non-fieldable entity. You can just store the node ID as an integer property on your entity, but obviously you won't get any of the entity reference UI goodness (autocomplete, using views to limit allowed choices, etc)

Comment: The problem is that I only want one table that i have to insert data into, if I use the entity reference field there will be several places that I have to insert data into and that's the problem. I would like to just use one table and be able to reference that data to a node, is that possible?

Comment: The field system will take care of adding/updating/removing the field data, you won't have to (and shouldn't) manipulate those tables manually. It sounds a bit like you want to use half of the entity system, and half your own custom solution. I wouldn't advise trying to do that; if you want to use Drupal's entity system, use it fully. That includes using fields where appropriate, which they are in your case

Comment: Thanks, I will try to use the entity reference module correct and see if that works good.

Comment: If I would like to add data from an external source to drupal DB is there any easy way to see what tables I should add that data into so the entity reference also will be created?